# Calculating the Limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos^5{x} + ax + b}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am studying for an entrance exam and would like somebody to confirm my answer or point out mistakes I made. Answers are greatly appreciated!

> Find a and b so that the following Limit exists.
>   $$ L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos^5{x} + ax + b}{x^2} $$

My solution approach was using l'Hôpital's rule so I set a to 0 and b to -1.
-1 cancels the 1 from cos 0 so I get 0/0 then I can use l'Hôpital's rule. Having a = 0 I can use it again.

Is this approach right?

Comment: Sure.  *First* set $b=-1$.  Use L'Hospital's Rule.  *Then* set $a=0$. End up with $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-5\cos^4 x\sin x}{2x}$. Limit of this *could* be done with L'Hospital's Rule, but shouldn't be, since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: @André: You're missing a minus sign from the cosine derivative there.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks. Middle of the night.

Comment: @entrance_exam: I personally prefer your/André's approach to the ones in the answers. Those are good to know and can be useful in other circumstances, but they involve more details if you spell them out rigorously.

Comment: @joriki.. But the problem asks to find all pairs $(a,b)$ such that the limit exists and if you start saying: "ok let's put $b=-1$..",  you are already considering a particular case. How would you proceed in order to eliminate all possible pairs except for $(a,b)=(0,-1)$?

Comment: The OP perhaps described the process non-optimally, in terms of a strategy based on L'H. Rule.  It really should have been something like this. If $b \ne -1$, the thing blows up near $0$.  So $b=-1$ is the only possibility worth chasing.  Use L'H. Rule. In the expression we obtain, if $a \ne 0$, we get blow-up. So $a=0$ is the only thing worth chasing.

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is correct. Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \cos
^{5}x+ax+b\right) =1+b$, for the limit $$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos
^{5}x+ax+b}{x^{2}}$$ to exist, $1+b$ must be $0$, which means $b=-1$. And
since  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{d}{dx}\left( \cos
^{5}x+ax-1\right) \right) =a,$$ for L to exist, $a$ must be $0$. The limit is

$$
L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left( \cos ^{5}x-1\right) }{\frac{d
}{dx}\left( x^{2}\right) }=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}-\frac{5}{2}\left( \cos
^{4}x\right) \frac{\sin x}{x}=-\frac{5}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+O(x^4)$, then try using the binomial theorem to get the first two non-zero terms for $\cos^5(x)$.

Comment: @Thijs: It would seem that for an entrance exam, one should be able to use whatever they know. So I guess I should have said, "If you know the Maclaurin series..."

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is right, however in an exam i would reason as follows. The problem in your limit is the $x^2$ at the denominator. As long as you can factor it out from the fraction everything is allright. So try to write
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$
and you can easily see that
$$\cos^5(x)=1+p(x)$$
where $p(x)$ is an infinite converging sum of monomials of degree at least $2$. Having noticed this, there is no way for your limit to exists unless $a=0$ and $b=-1$. This part of the reasinonig shows that, if you want your limit to exists, then necessarily $a=0,\: b=-1$. On the other hand, if $a=0,\: b=-1$, then a simple evaluation shows that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^5(x)-1}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{5\cos^4(x)\sin(x)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{5\cos^4(x)}{2}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=-\frac{5}{2}.$$
Hope everything is clear.

Comment: Robjohn was quicker...

Comment: Generally, "speed" should not play a role in accepting answers. Rather, one should strive to accept the answer that one thinks will help the most readers. For example, if one answer serves a fish on a platter, but another answer teaches one how to fish, then generally one should accept the latter (this remark is not specific to this thread - it's a general remark).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ $ If as $\rm\ x\to 0:\: $ $\rm\ f(x)\to f_0,\ \ f{\:\:'}(x)\to f_1,\ \ f(x)/x^2\to f_2\ $ for $\rm\:f_i \in\mathbb R\ $  then $\rm\ f_0 = 0 = f_1\:.$

**Proof** $\ $ If $\rm\ f_0\ne 0\ $ then $\rm\:f(x)/x^2\to\: f_0/0^+ = \infty\not\in\mathbb R\:.\:$ Thus $\rm\:f_0 = 0\:.\:$ Similarly $\rm\:f_1 = 0\:,\:\: $ else

$$\rm f_1 \ne 0\:\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ f_2\: =\  \lim_{x\:\to\: 0}\ \frac{f(x)}{x^2}\ =\ \lim_{x\: \to\: 0}\ \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}}{x}\ \to\ \frac{f_1}{0}\ =\ \pm \infty\ \not\in\: \mathbb R$$
$\ $
So for $\rm\ f(x)\: =\: cos^5(x)+a\:x+b\:,\ \ f(0) = 0\:\Rightarrow\: b=-1\:,\:$ and $\rm\ f{\:\:'}(x)\: =\: -5\ cos^4(x)\ sin(x)+a\ $ hence $\rm\: f{\:\:'}(0) = 0\:\Rightarrow\:a = 0\:.$

**REMARK** $\ $ If you know about [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) then it should be clear that the above amounts to computing a Taylor series approximant.

Answer (score 1):

Something without l'Hospital. It is clear that $b=-1$ as mentioned above.

$$ L = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos^5{x} + ax -1}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\left( \frac{\cos^5 x-1}{x^2}+\frac{a}{x} \right)$$

But

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^5 x-1}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}(1+\cos x+...+\cos^4 x)=\frac{5}{4} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}^2}=-\frac{5}{2}$$

Therefore, if $a \neq 0$ the limit does not exist.